# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. DNN9

Tags: object, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.-- DNN 9**
[image]

Downloaded DNN 9 and pointed in IIS but getting above error while trying to browse.

Comment: https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/releases/tag/v9.0.1
download upgrade version and replace current instance
Reff:http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/learn/video-library/view-video/video/556/view/details/upgrading-a-local-dotnetnuke-pe-installation

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/releases/tag/v9.0.1
download upgrade version and replace current instance
Reff:http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/learn/video-library/view-video/video/556/view/details/upgrading-a-local-dotnetnuke-pe-installation